# Proofs related to Newton's Method

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have the inductive sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$
I need to prove the following:

(b) Suppose $f', f'', f(x_1)>0$. Show that $x_1 > x_2 > x_3 >...>c$, where c is the x-intercept of f.

(c) Let $$\delta_k=x_k-c=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)}$$ for some $\epsilon_k\in(c,x_k)$. Show that $$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)}-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$$ Conclude that:$$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(x_k)}f''(\eta_k)(x_k-\epsilon_k)$$

(d) Let $m=f'(c)=inf(f')$ on $[c,x_1]$ and $M=sup(f'')$ on the same interval. Show that Newton's method works if $x_1-c<\frac{m}{M}$

**What I know:**

(b) $f(x)$ is certainly positive for all $x\in(c,x_1]$, and so is $f'$, so thus $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is positive from $x_1$ to $c$. The rest of the proof should come easily once I can show that any $x_n>c$, as I can then do the rest inductively. So what I'm having trouble with here is proving that c is the lower bound for the sequence.

(c) I know how to prove the first part of the question, as I can simply substitute the expressions for $\delta_{k+1}$ with the corresponding ones for $\delta_k$. However, for the second part of the question, while I can see that it's clearly a proof making use of the mean value theorem derived from the expression for $\delta_{k+1}$, the exact mechanics of the proof are lost on me.

**Edit 2:** I solved that portion of the proof, but I also need to show that $\delta_{k+1}\leq \frac{f''(\eta_k)}{f'(x_k)}\delta_k^2$

(d) I think I'm supposed to run a convergence test based on the conclusion in (c), but I'm not sure.

**Edit:** (b) has been solved

Comment: Part b is essentially geometric: a convex function lies above its tangent lines. So if $L_k$ are the tangent lines to $f$ at $x_k$ then $L_k(x_{k+1})=0$ while $f(x_{k+1})>0$, while means $x_{k+1}>c$ since $f'$ is everywhere positive. I'll wait on a bit more input from you to talk about the rest.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? You lost me somewhere during the second half of your explanation.

Comment: You have $f''>0$ so $f$ is convex, so it lies above its tangent lines. Newton's method is defined by finding the root of the tangent line at $x_k$, which we can denote by $L_k$. This root is $x_{k+1}$. Since $f$ lies above its tangent lines and $L_k(x_{k+1})=0$, it follows that $f(x_{k+1})>0$. (Note that here we need that $x_k>c$, which is part of the inductive hypothesis). Since $f'>0$, it then follows that $x_{k+1}>c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you have already shown that this is true:
$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)}-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$
And you have figured out that you need to use the mean value theorem to get to:
$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(x_k)}f''(\eta_k)(x_k-\epsilon_k)$.

$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)f'(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(f_k)}-\frac{f(x_k)f'(\epsilon_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(x_k)}$

$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(x_k)}(f'(x_k)-f'(\epsilon_k))$

$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(x_k)}\frac{f'(x_k)-f'(\epsilon)}{x_k-\epsilon_k}(x_k-\epsilon_k)$

Mean value theorem says $\exists \eta \in(x_k,\epsilon_k)$ such that $f''(\eta) = \frac{f'(x_k)-f'(\epsilon)}{x_k-\epsilon_k}$.
$\delta_{k+1}=\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)f'(x_k)}f''(\eta_k)(x_k-\epsilon_k)$.

$\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(\epsilon_k)} = \delta_k$

$c<\epsilon_k<x_k$

$(x_k-\epsilon_k)<(x_k-c)$

$(x_k-\epsilon_k)<\delta_k$

$f''(\eta_k)<M,f'(x_k)>m$

$\delta_{k+1}<\frac{M}{m} \delta_k^2$.

if$\frac{M}{m} \delta_1<n<1$ then $\delta_k<n^k$ and $\delta_k$ converges to $0$.

$\frac{M}{m} \delta_1<1$

$ \delta_1<\frac{m}{M}$

If $x_1-c<\frac{m}{M}$, $x_k$ converges to $c$.

QED

Comment: Is the final part sufficient to show (c)?

Comment: I would spell it out.